# Creating arrays and datasets with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, addition

I write a code that will arrange me a points sinside table, but when I specific arrayOfDivs all works great: http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/6

```
var arrayOfDivs = [({topPosition : 99, leftPosition: 100}),({topPosition : 150, leftPosition: 400}),({topPosition : 578, leftPosition: 10})];
```

When I try to dinamicly creating this arrayOfDivs based on other things, when I add this code to create arrayOfDivs:

```
var arrayOfDivs = [];

$("#table .draggable").each(function(index, item){
   var lat = $(item).attr("lat");
   var lng = $(item).attr("lng");
   var top = $(this).position().top;
   var left = $(this).position().left;
   arrayOfDivs.push({topPosition : top, leftPosition: left, lat : lat, lng : lng});
});

var height = $('table').height();
var rowsCount = $('table tr').length;
var ROW_HEIGHT = height/rowsCount;
```

FINAL VERSION: http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/10/ , I just get this error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Why? What is the prob;em?

Answer (score 1):

Your `arrayOfDivs` is being created successfully.

The `TypeError` is occurring on a line not shown in your question. It's here:

```
var rowNumber = Math.floor(position.topPosition / ROW_HEIGHT);
rows[rowNumber].push(position);
```

Because `position.topPosition` can be negative that means `rowNumber` can be negative, which means that you're trying to do `rows[-1].push(position)` which is essentially `undefined.push(position)`.

([Add a `console.log(rowNumber);` statement](http://jsfiddle.net/u58k6/12/) just before the `.push()` and you'll see the -1.)

You don't have this problem when you hard-code the `arrayOfDivs` because none of the positions that you've specified are negative. It's when you get the positions of actual elements on the page that you might get negative numbers.

I don't have a specific suggestion for how to fix this, because I'm not (yet) sure what you're actually trying to achieve. But I hope that's enough for you to go on to fix it yourself.

Comment: I try but again is the same Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Comment: what I try to do is: arragnge divs in arrays , first by rows, so one row = one new array, after that arrange by left every new array created

Comment: please try to fix that

Comment: Well you could add _if(rowNumber<0){ rowNumber = 0; }_ just after the _var_ statement I quoted.